# Is this bubble sort variation or altogether a different one?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, array-algorithms

I was implementing bubble sort, I came up with this :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BubbleSort550 {
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
      
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
              String[] temp = br.readLine().split("\\s+");
              int[] arr = new int[temp.length];

              for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
              }
              for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++){
                   if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                     int inTemp = arr[j];
                     arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                     arr[j+1] = inTemp;
                   }
                                 
                }
              }

              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }catch(IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

This is Bubble sort, to the best of my knowledge correct me if I am wrong here.

But what about the following one, this also works, at least in all the cases, as far as I have tested, this has worked.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BubbleSort550 {
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
      
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
              String[] temp = br.readLine().split("\\s+");
              int[] arr = new int[temp.length];

              for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
              }
              for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
                   if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                     int inTemp = arr[j];
                     arr[j] = arr[i];
                     arr[i] = inTemp;
                   }
                }
              }

              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }catch(IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

I feel this is correct, it doesn't seem to me as bubble sort, as the basic premise of bubble sort is that the largest number should bubble up in each pass, which is not happening in the second implementation, and I am not sure either which standard sorting algorithm is the above implementation following. Well I am not at all sure whether the second one is correct at all.

Comment: The second snippet is a (sort of) selection sort. It finds the smallest element and puts it in the first position. It then finds the second smallest element, etc. A proper implementation would find the smallest element, and then perform a single swap to put it into the first position.

Comment: In the second one, you are assuming that the smallest bubble is already at the top.  Have you tried it on a reverse ordered set eg 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.  If you count the exchanges and there are none then the sort is complete.

Comment: @user3386109 that would be a selection sort: not a bubble sort.  In a bubblesort, the bubbles change positions until the list is ordered.

Comment: @cup Yes, that's my point. The second snippet is neither a bubble sort nor a (properly implemented) selection sort, but it's closer to a selection sort.

Comment: @cup What do you mean by "if there are no more exchanges then the sort is complete"? Yes I have checked it on a reverse ordered set. It worked.

Comment: If in iteration you don't swipe any element in bubble sort you are done, so it is better to use while loop.